# Raspberry PI gpio turning on and off without a reason

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio, lcd

I was trying to control an LCD using buttons I made with this code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import drivers 
from time import sleep
display = drivers.Lcd()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN)
while True:
    display.lcd_clear()
    button1 = GPIO.input(17)
    if (button1 == 1):
        display.lcd_display_string("Button: True", 1)
    else:
        display.lcd_display_string("Button: False", 1)
```

First I wasn't having button plugged in (Output was `True` consistently). I plugged the button in.
Then output started to randomly go `True` and `False`. I pressed button it was consistently `True`.

I need to fix this `True`/`False` wobbling.

I tried adding ground to the gpio pin. But it just makes it always `False`.

Comment: Configure pull up or pull down  to fix non-active state. After that, read what "debounce"  means and what is for. After this exersise drop all your code into the trash bin and use existing kernel driver `gpio-keys`.